# Moving database from WP 2.6 to 3.5 problem

Tags: database, migration

I recently moved my database from a wp 2.6 blog to a wp 3.5 form using [this posts advice](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26277/upgrade-wordpress-database-from-2-6-to-3-2/100694#100694). (Alex Miller's answer).  Everything looked good on the home page; however, when I click on an individual article, I get an error message that says:

> "The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Because I was also switching to a new URL, I also added the following code to the wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Any suggestions why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Try upgrading WordPress on the old server/url first, and then move your site to the new server/url

Comment: There are too many moving parts in such considerable version jump and URL change at the same time. Try to split this into several steps and localize at which point the issue appears.